# n = n +1 is faster than n++ or ++n, why?

Tags: javascript, performance, increment

Check this test case: http://jsperf.com/n-n-1-or-n

```
n = n + 1;
```

is faster than

```
n++;
```

and

```
++n;
```

Any clue about why the first writing is so much faster on many browsers ?

Comment: Unless your code is actually doing 50,000,000 of these operations per second, you are wasting your time worrying about this.

Comment: you wont see much difference over few iterations

Comment: @Downvoters I'd actually like to know the reason behind this out of interest, since the jsPerf seems intact.

Comment: @Andrew - That's not what the OP is asking. The question is whether to avoid `--` and `++`.

Comment: Andrew was right, my question in the body was different than the one in the title. I've edited the body to clarify.

Comment: @James Mitch: calm down.

Comment: @JamesMitch While I agree with the point you're making, I have strong opinions against the way you express it. First of all it's inappropriate to be rude (that includes being rude towards true idiots too). Second of all, it's hardly going to change the state of things. In fact, I was considering **not to** upvote the question simply because of your rant. (I did upvote it, eventually, but I was really tempted to skip that.) If you're going to get upset every time some ass is doing something wrong, you'll end up being upset most of your time. :)

Comment: Testing such short code that way is not representative. If you e.g. run the code a second time in chrome with `Run again` then the `n = n + 1` is not the fastest. Also the `console.log(n);` influences the result. There e.g. it could happen, that you test how well the browsers performs if the log list reaches a certain internal limit. (removing it has a complete other result). Anyway none of the results will really reflect which would perform better in a real world application.

Answer (score 6):

The performance will differ by browser and computer.

I see that `n = n + 1` on my setup is about 4 times faster.

At the same time, the slowest is over 62 **million** ops per second.

You are micro-optimizing here. The usage of one over another is *hardly* going to be a bottleneck.

---

Why it is faster in **some** browsers? I don't know. You would need to dig into the source code of the different JavaScript engines to find out.

Chances are good that there is an optimization for this case due to how some popular micro-benchmarks are written.

Comment: Aren't you curious about why it's 4 times faster?

Comment: @Andrew - I don't know. The JS engines either specifically optimize for it, but it is also very possible that they first transform the `++` and `--` operators to the first form, slowing everything down.

Comment: @Andrew - No, not particularly. JS engines change and get optimized by their creators for different reasons. I wouldn't be surprised if this is the result of optimizing for some popular micro-benchmark.

Comment: It's the real goal of my question. To understand why it's 4 times faster. I know that in the real world, this has no real noticeable impact.

Comment: I did: "n = n +1 is faster than n++ or ++n, **why?**"

Comment: @wewereweb - "Should we avoid to use ++ and -- operators ?" is the question in the body.

Comment: @Andrew - Ok, sorry it was my first question on stackoverflow, it was not that clear. But i guess that you are right with the js engine first transforming n++ into n = n + 1. Probably the best explaination.
I edited my question body.

Answer (score 2):

Check this test. Or [here](http://jsperf.com/n-n-1-or-n) is another test.
[image: preformace test]

Comment: So, first of all, we can conclude that the company delivering stuff with bite marks on their fruit is the slowest (just wanted to point that out because I really dislike them, hehe). Second of all, and that's the real point, there seems to be some consistency in some expressions running slower. While it's hardly a cause of a bottleneck, this discrepancy begs the question - what more unexpected differences are there. I had no idea that there was a difference. Now, I'm curious and want to know more. +1 for the image.

Comment: Actually, since the units are operations per second, Safari is the fastest of the tested browsers, not the slowest.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Darn... You're point is absolutely correct. I missed that part and will have to stand corrected. I wonder why IE isn't included in the chart... It's either really high or really low. :)